how can i change my python debugger to normal instead of break point cause in breakpoint when my code runs it doesnot print output
i want an output of my program but instead this debugger gives me folder path in vs code
def remove_duplicate(list):
unique = []
for item in list:
if item not in unique:
unique.append(item)
return unique
list = [12,12,22,22]
print(remove_duplicate(list))
I want the output of this program but instead this pops up in vs code terminal 51501' '--' 'C:\Users\acer\Desktop\python folder.vscode\duplicate.py' '--username'
'peter' '--account' 'stack overflow'

Please use formatting and consider deliver a Stackblitz link, so people will more likely react on your issue.
